Labels on a pie chart not pointing to the correct segment in R
I want to make a simple pie chart but all the labels are pointing to the wrong segment. They labels seem to be mirrored or might have a faulty ypos. I understand that ypos means the position of the labels on the outline of the pie chart, but is there any way that I can mirror the labels in the graph?
RNA <- Final_Vaccine %>%
  filter(Vaccine_Tech == "RNA") %>%
  group_by(Pathogen) %>%
  summarise(Count = n()) %>%
  ungroup()
RNA <- RNA %>%
  mutate(Percent = Count / sum(Count) * 100,
         ypos = cumsum(Percent) - 0.5 * Percent)

The table then looks like this:
(https://i.sstatic.net/lGBjLmW9.png)
ggplot(RNA, aes(x = "", y = Percent, fill = Pathogen)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  geom_label_repel(aes(y = ypos, label = paste0(round(Percent, 1), "%")),
                   nudge_x = 1, nudge_y = 0, size = 4, show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel2") +
  labs(title = "RNA Vaccines pathogens")

Pie Chart looks like this:
(https://i.sstatic.net/TvbuTbJj.png)
I have tried modifying the ypos, putting minus signs. If there are any solutions to recifying the ypos or making the labels point to the correct segment, I would be very grateful.

Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. You are more likely to get a helpful answer if you provide the data (or some example / subsample) of it. I have seen you gave a screenshot of View(RNA). Ideally, you would include a piece of code that creates the RNA data frame and results in the same problem, so to make it easy to reproduce.

Try with geom_label_repel(..., position = "stack"). Otherwise the labels don't get stacked.
